# NaNs at the end of an array are creeping in when using interp1d

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, interpolation, nan

I have 2 2D arrays of x and y positions that express values of a contour plot. As I translate the contour plot multiple times, I need to track the original coordinates as they move too, so that I can express a final displacement at all points of the original image.

I am writing in python3 using scipy.interpolate.interp1d. After one iteration, I have no problems, and the coordinates have been successfully interpolated back onto the original grid. I print out the final 10 elements of one of the columns in the 2D array:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
print(y_coordinate[-10:, 20])
>>> [ 60.  61.  62.  63.  64.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

I have nans because the displacement was -5 in the y direction of an image 64 pixels wide, so the 5 pixels at the top have shifted down. The problem is, that in the next step I have zero displacement in the y direction, so the points do not move here, but they might move elsewhere in my large array, so need to interpolate over the entire array.

I interpolate column by column using scipy.interpolate.interp1d as so (and remove the indices of the array for clarity, but know they are the same as the previous lines above):

```
f = interp1d(y, y_coordinate, kind='linear', bounds_error = False)
new_y_coordinate = f(y)
```

where y_coordinate is as printed out above, y is

```
>>>[55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64]
```

So essentially I want it to return the exact same values as they already lie on the points I want it to interpolate onto. Instead, I get this:

```
print(new_y_coordinate)
>>> [ 60.  61.  62.  63.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

I've got the nan creeping in to good data. What's strange is first of all I tried this with complex numbers and thought it was an error to do with those. I then changed it to be two arrays of real numbers and found the error was solved on the left hand side of the array (for x direction translations) but is now occurring on the top for y displacement translations. A simple test I did with a similar situation didn't have this error at all.

Any ideas on what is happening and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `fill_value='extrapolate'` in `interp1d`. Just in case you can also filter `nan` values using a mask. Code:

```
# assuming they are not np.arrays to begin with
y_coordinate = np.asarray(y_coordinate)   
y = np.asarray(y)

mask = ~np.isnan(y)
f = interp1d(y[mask], y_coordinate[mask], kind='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value='extrapolate')
```

Comment: Thing is I don't want it to extrapolate. I am happy with the initial nan values being there, as they were outside of the x domain. What I want to know is why I lose that  [-6] element - it was 64 then gets turned into a nan, even though my line of code should interpolate that value onto the position 59, then when passing through
    f(y)
should also give me 64 at position 59.
(I had to edit as I accidentally posted half way through writing)

Comment: Hi Steven, I have no idea why. As a rule you should put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce your code. Have you tried the solution and see if it works? You can remove `fill_value='extrapolate'` and pass the mask: including `nan` values in interpolation is generally not recommended.